# Change Size of ColorPicker Dialog android

Tags: android, color-picker

I have used **Colorpickerdialog** in API Demos. It works fine in emulator of size WVGA,HVGA. But in Small size(QVGA) the dialog cut at the bottom. And i run in small size realdevice too, but the same problem it shows. Need suggestion for reducing the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by initializing the CENTER X,Y and radius, like

```
    private static final int CENTER_X = 80;
    private static final int CENTER_Y = 80;
    private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;
```

And it will run in all size of emulator.